# The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins

I wrote into app.yml and application.properties.
server.servlet.context-path=/xyz

But still deploy failed. Sometimes deploy succeed sometimes fails. but always build success. What can be the reason?

Comment: can you post the error trace ?

Comment: Deploying /.......war to container Tomcat 8.x Remote with context 
  Redeploying [...........war]
  Undeploying [.......... .war]
  Deploying [..........war]
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [/....war]

Comment: Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/xyz] but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message

Comment: check If  all the instances of Tomcat is stop check the port on which you are deploying your tomcat is available also check if the context path is unique that is unique for  all the applications you deploy on that container.

Comment: FAIL - Application at context path [/xyz] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/xyz]]]

Comment: Without jenkins Is it working in Your Local Machine? means Have you deployed directly to tomcat server?

Comment: yes ,its working

Comment: Are you using spring boot?

Comment: yes, ı used spring boot